# How does linux (reboot) notifier list work?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, qemu

I am testing the reboot notifier hook on Linux kernel 5.8 running on QEMU ARM64 with busybox rootfs. This is my first time using a notifier list, so I might be wrong. I have add one reboot notifier which is executed well, but I have also added a second item to the list using `.next` and the handler of this notifier does not execute. Here's the snippet from my dummy driver:

```c
static int reboot_handler_first(struct notifier_block *this, unsigned long action,
        void *data)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "first reboot notifier called\n");
    return 0;
}

static int reboot_handler_second(struct notifier_block *this, unsigned long action,
        void *data)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "second reboot notifier called\n");
    return 0;
}

static struct notifier_block reboot_notifier_second = {
    .notifier_call = reboot_handler_second,
    .next = NULL,
    .priority = INT_MAX,
};

static struct notifier_block reboot_notifier_first = {
    .notifier_call = reboot_handler_first,
    .next = &reboot_notifier_second,
    .priority = INT_MAX,
};
```

Here, the `reboot_handler_first()` gets called but I do not see any log from `reboot_handler_second()`. I was expecting that `reboot_notifer_first()` will trigger `reboot_notifier_second()` but that does not seem to be the case. Am I missing anything?

Below are the logs that I see with this kernel and busybox rootfs:

```
/ # reboot
/ # umount: devtmpfs busy - remounted read-only
swapoff: can't open '/etc/fstab': No such file or directory
The system is going down NOW!
Sent SIGTERM to all processes
Sent SIGKILL to all processes
Requesting system reboot
[   20.158023] first reboot notifier called
[   20.232718] reboot: Restarting system
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0000000000 [0x411fd070]
```

**EDIT**

This is how my `module_init(hello_init)` function looks like. I have registered only the first reboot notifier `reboot_notifier_first` and then set its next to point to the `reboot_notifier_second`. Please correct me. My understanding is that I need to register the first notifier with `register_reboot_notifier()` and then I just need to set the `.next` of current `notifier_block` to add new nodes to the linked list. This way I will get a chain of notifier blocks.

```
static int __init hello_init(void)
{
    int rc;

    rc = register_reboot_notifier(&reboot_notifier_first);
    printk(KERN_INFO "This is from init\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how the linked lists work? There is a special API which you have to call to add a node to the list. I.o.w. the `->next` pointer is set up by a framework, and not by the caller. You have to show in your snippet how you have done that.

Comment: `.next = &reboot_notifier_second` that's the only think I did. My understanding is that once we set the `next` of the first notifier, the FW will iterate this linked list to process first notifier and then second notifier in sequence

Comment: You didn't get what I have asked you nor provided a crucial part of your code.

Comment: Where do you register your notifier? `of the first notifier, the FW will iterate this linked list to process` Which one is the "first"? Why do you set `.next = &reboot_notifier_second,` manually instead of registering it? `Am I missing anything?` My guess is your `reboot_notifier_first.next` is just being overwritten when registering it into the list...

Comment: Please see the EDIT. I think I now get what you are trying to tell. I should not be editing the `.next` pointer myself, rather I should keep calling the `register_reboot_notifier()` for every new notifier block and the framework will itself adjust the links.

Comment: With the approach told in above comment, I got the expected output.